# How to change the source IP randomly via iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to send part of traffic from random source IPs.

I've got an interface like:

```
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 1.2.3.4/23 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 85366sec preferred_lft 85366sec
    inet 1.2.4.5/32 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Normally all the traffic leaves from `1.2.3.4`, so I added an iptable entry:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ent3 \
  -p tcp -m tcp --syn \
  -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5 \
  -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.4.5
```

But it never seems to be triggered.

It does work if I use `-s 1.2.3.4`, but I'd like to use the interface instead.

Comment: You write "ent3" with a T, instead of "enS3" in your iptables rule...

Comment: @Dom how is that not a runtime error? I'm reaching new levels of anger here :D Thanks for spotting the issue.

Comment: The interface might only exist after iptables rules have been loaded. So it accepts anything.